# What are the best methods to reduce the bag of words dimensionality?

Tags: nlp

I have a small text dataset with 600 comments. My task is a binary classification one. In order to train my model, I transformed the comments into a bag of words using sklearn CountVectorizer. The vocabulary has 1800 words, which is way bigger than the amount of comments. So, how can I reduce the dimensionality of my dataset? I want to know this because I believe that this bigger vocabulary is a problem for the model. I know methods to reduce dimentionality, like PCA, but I do not know if it is as useful in the context of text classification as it is in a tabular dataset. I am also new to nlp, so I wonder if there is a better way to reduce dimensionality, like a way to choose the best words in the vocabulary and use only those.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a pre-trained embedding space. The pre-trained embedding space will have much lower dimensionality and most likely all of the words in your corpus will be in it.